# Provide access to the Internet via NAT on the one router from the network separated by another router

Tags: linux, networking, routing, nat

I've got the following network topology:

1. **Router1** on Linux VM with enp0s3/192.168.56.10 looking to the local network **lan1** and enp0s8/192.168.88.5 looking to the Internet. NAT is configured on the **router1** via iptabels masquerading of 192.168.56.0/24 source packets, IP forwarding is on. All the machines in 192.168.56.0/24 do have access to the Internet via NAT on this router.
2. **Router2** on Linux VM with enp0s3/192.168.56.100 and enp0s8/192.168.57.10/27 looking to another local network **lan2**. IP forwarding is on. The **router2** itself does have access to the Intenet, but all the other machines in the **lan2** (192.168.57.0/27) do not have access to the Internet.

I've managed to provide access to the internet for the **lan2** (192.168.57.0/27) machines by turning on second NAT on **router2**, but is this the right way to do it? Can I achive intenet accessability for machines in **lan2** by pure routing via **router1** or something else?

Routing tables are as follows:

router1 192.168.56.10/192.168.88.5:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s8
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s8
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.57.0    192.168.56.100  255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
```

router2 192.168.56.100/192.168.57.10:

```
default         192.168.56.10   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s8
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 enp0s8
```

lan2 vm 192.168.57.6:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.57.10   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 enp0s3
```

Comment: Standard question: What do you see in a packet capture, at various points? Is it that packets from lan2 don't reach router1, or is it that they don't exit out to your WAN, or is it that they're being sent fine but you're not getting any replies back?

Comment: `masquerading of 192.168.56.0/24 source packets` if you don't want to "double NAT", you'll need to masquerade for `192.168.57.0/27` on router 1 as well.

Comment: @u1686_grawity
thank you, good sir! After I've studied tcpdumps on all the interfaces of my setup, it appeared that there was no route to 192.168.57.0/27 on the main router (192.168.88.1/24), after I've added it everything works fine! Again thank you for the tip in diagnostics!!

Answer (score 2):

According to mr. @u1686_grawity's recommendations in the comments, I've checked with tcpdump all the interfaces in my network topology and it appeared that there were no route to 192.168.57.0/27 on the main router 192.168.88.1. After I've added a static route, machines from 192.168.57.0/27 now has access to the Internet without **double NAT**.
If someone's woundering, the static route is like this (it's hardware Microtik):

```
On router 192.168.88.1
dst 192.168.57.0/27 via 192.168.88.5
```